# Beautiful soup extract tag content but excluding certain string using regex or other

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I have a html file with multiple tables (2 of which are below). I would like to extract the string Quatermass 2 and Ghostbusters only from any tags which have "width": "41%". My problem is that 'Title' is in every table "width": "41%" also and I would like not to extract that.

```
        <table width='100%' border='0' cellpadding='0' class='blackbg textheadtitle'>
            <tr>
                <td width='41%' align='left'>Title</td>
                <td width='10%' align='left'>Year</td>
                    <table width='99%' border='0' cellpadding='1' class="normal">
            <tr>
                <td width='41%' align='left'><strong>Quatermass 2</strong></td>
                <td width='10%' align='left'>1957</td>


        <table width='100%' border='0' cellpadding='0' class='blackbg textheadtitle'>
            <tr>
                <td width='41%' align='left'>Title</td>
                <td width='10%' align='left'>Year</td>
                    <table width='99%' border='0' cellpadding='1' class="normal">
            <tr>
                <td width='41%' align='left'><strong>Quatermass 3</strong></td>
                <td width='10%' align='left'>1958</td>
```

This code enables me print tag content were {"width": "41%"}

```
html = ['table.html']

with open("table.html", "r") as f:
    contents = f.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, "lxml")
for name in soup.find_all("td", {"width": "41%"}):
    print((name).get_text()
```

Output is

```
Title
Quatermass 2
Title
Ghostbusters
```

I have tried using the not equal operator in the print statement but it doesn't work.

```
for name in soup.find_all("td", {"width": "41%"}):
    print((name).get_text(!='Title'))
```

Is there a regex clause I can add in the find_all function that will exclude the 'Title' string?

Comment: Your example string does not contain `Ghostbusters`, only `Quatermass 3`

Answer (score 1):

You may pass a `^(?!Title$)` regex that matches any string but `Title` to the `find_all` method:

```
import re
#...
for name in soup.find_all("td", {"width": "41%"}, string=re.compile(r'^(?!Title$)')):
    print((name).get_text())
```

Output:

```
Quatermass 2
Quatermass 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `CSS` Selector and `:not(:contains(text))`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html='''<table width='100%' border='0' cellpadding='0' class='blackbg textheadtitle'>
            <tr>
                <td width='41%' align='left'>Title</td>
                <td width='10%' align='left'>Year</td>
                    <table width='99%' border='0' cellpadding='1' class="normal">
            <tr>
                <td width='41%' align='left'><strong>Quatermass 2</strong></td>
                <td width='10%' align='left'>1957</td>


        <table width='100%' border='0' cellpadding='0' class='blackbg textheadtitle'>
            <tr>
                <td width='41%' align='left'>Title</td>
                <td width='10%' align='left'>Year</td>
                    <table width='99%' border='0' cellpadding='1' class="normal">
            <tr>
                <td width='41%' align='left'><strong>Quatermass 3</strong></td>
                <td width='10%' align='left'>1958</td>'''
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
for tag in soup.select("td[width='41%']:not(:contains(Title))"):
    print(tag.text)
```